# Did Augustine try to prove God's existence using Set Theory?

Tags: theology, philosophy-of-religion, infinity, christianity, augustine

Some time ago I heard a professor of mine describe Augustine's Confessions as an attempt to prove God's existence using set theory. I didn't get a chance to ask him more of what he meant, and wondering if anyone has any further ideas on this, or knows of anyone else who discusses it. I know that after the account of his conversion he gets into discussions of infinity and things related, but would love an explanation of how this equates to or can be seen as being derived from set theory (or some elementary form of set theory).

Comment: See [Drozdek, Beyond Infinity: Augustine and Cantor](https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/ltp/1995-v51-n1-ltp2151/400897ar.pdf).